# How to get crashed process id from a minidump file

Tags: crashpad

My application is developed with Electron(v11.1.1), and it uses crashpad to catch all crash dmp files from every processes.
How can I get crashed process id or other meta data from a minidump file

Comment: You can use breakpad-tools to inspect the minidump, but I don't see the process id (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66962054/c-node-addon-macho-symbols-for-sentry-native)

Answer (score 0):

I found that we can parse some field directly from the dmp file

```
async function parseProcessDetailFromDump(dumpPath) {
  return new Promise((ok, fail) => {
    const readStream = fs.createReadStream(dumpPath)
    let ptype = null
    let pid = null
    readStream.on("data", (chunk) => {
      const text = chunk.toString(`utf-8`)
      const lines = text.split(path.sep)
      for (const line of lines) {
        const found = line.match(/ptype/)
        if (found != null && found.length > 0) {
          const regPtype = /(?<=ptype[^0-9a-zA-Z]+)[0-9a-zA-Z]+/gu
          const regPid = /(?<=pid[^0-9a-zA-Z]+)[0-9a-zA-Z]+/gu
          ptype = line.match(regPtype)[0]
          pid = line.match(regPid)[0]
        }
      }
    })
    readStream.on("error" , () => {
      rejects()
    })
    readStream.on("end", () => {
      ok({pid, ptype})
    })
  })
}
```