# C++ node-addon MachO Symbols for Sentry Native

Tags: c++, macos, sentry

I'm trying to get debug symbols for a node addon working so that I can monitor crashes inside of the node addon. I've got this working with breakpad symbols, but not with MachO symbols. I'm just curious if this is expected.

I'm also writing this question to document my work, because I was quite confused by the Sentry docs.

## Using breakpad successfully

- Download and build `https://github.com/getsentry/breakpad-tools`
- `cd macos/build` (or linux)
- `./dump_syms ~/path/to/addon.node > addon.sym`
- `../../scripts/cp-symbols.sh symbols/ addon.sym` # This just copies the file into the correct directory, so that `minidump_stackwalk` works
- `./minidump_stackwalk minidump_crashed_file.dmp symbols/` # Test that the symbols look good
- `sentry-cli upload-dif symbols/addon.node/generated_uuid_thing/addon.node.sym`

## Comparison with MachO/dSYM

Instead of `dump_syms`, I tried `dsymutil` as the [Sentry docs suggest](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/native/guides/minidumps/data-management/debug-files/file-formats/), but that didn't work.

Here's the upload comparison:

[image]

So it looks like `dump_syms` generates a breakpad file, whereas `dsymutil` generates a macho file.

The MachO symbol generates a cryptic error on Sentry: "The debug information file used was broken", even though `sentry-cli difutil check` works fine.

Comment: It seems part of the problem is machine-dependent, and file-dependent. A coworker of mine found `dsymutil` work just fine for him. And when I tried a different C++ program it worked fine for me on my computer. One difference is that I'm on Mojave and he's on Big Sur.

Comment: Also something more I learned: there are more Sentry docs related to debug symbols in a different location, and also talks about c++ source bundles: https://docs.sentry.io/product/cli/dif/